# Single exec with multiple WebSocket requests

Tags: gatling

In my Gatling simulation, I have a list of WebSocket requests that are currently called one after another:

```
.exec(ws("1").sendText("1").check("..."))
.exec(ws("2").sendText("2").check("..."))
.exec(ws("3").sendText("3").check("..."))
```

The problem with that is that the checks arrive at different times and they cause test failures. Using a blocking check via `wsAwait` is not possible because of the requirements.

What I would like to have instead is a **single** check that collects all the responses. Ideally, it would look something like this:

```
.exec(
  ws("1").sendText("1"),
  ws("2").sendText("2"),
  ws("3").sendText("3")
  ).check(...)
```

This is, however, not possible currently. Is there a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you take a look at [Assertions](http://gatling.io/docs/2.0.0-RC2/general/assertions.html). This will allow you to make an assertion at the end of your simulation; so each scenario will run fully and then you can fail it based on whatever criteria you would like.

Alternatively you could define the exec calls as [resources](http://gatling.io/docs/2.0.0-RC2/http/http_request.html?highlight=resource#resources) and have the check come after them.

```
.exec(ws("1").sendText("1").resources(
      ws("2").sendText("2"),
      ws("3").sendText("3")
    ).check(...))
```

Comment: I don't want to use assertions as I don't want to create dozens of small simulations. These WS requestd should all be sent and read within a single WS connection. Also, unlike `http`, you cannot use `resources` like that with `ws`. Your answer won't compile.

Comment: You mention that you have used `wsAwait`, a blocking check, but you cannot use non-blocking checks (`wsListen`). Can you go in to more detail? `The expect` function also comes to mind but I have no experience with that one.

Comment: I made a mistake in the question: `wsAwait` is a blocking operation, which would not allow next `exec()` to be executed until the `check` returns. In our scenario, we don't have this. Users send requests and in an async fashion they get their replies back from the server. One workaround to my question is using `wsListen` and set `within` to a very long time - just to make sure that `check` returns. I'm looking for a more elegant solution though.

Comment: I've exhausted my knowledge of websockets with gatling here so I can't really suggest anything further. You may have more luck at their [user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gatling) - the big contributors seem active there.